# Recurring spurious errors with GORM dynamic finders

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I posted a related question a while back (without getting a full solution), but I need to post again because the problem I have has become a little wider in scope and is driving me crazy. Quite frequently (but intermittently) I am getting what are wholly spurious GORM errors, which I can only solve by doing a `grails clean`, which is obviously rather tiresome. I'd like to get to the bottom of what is causing this.

The latest is this error:

`2017-10-27 15:55:23,565 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /myapp/customer/searchOwing
No signature of method: myapp.Customer.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

The line which is causing this is this: `def list=Customer.list()`. I.e., a perfectly innocuous GORM list query which certainly shouldn't trigger a MissingMethodException. Can anyone think of why such problems might be occurring and how to prevent them? As I said, the problem is intermittent - sometimes the error occurs and sometimes it doesn't, with no change in the code.

Grails 2.2.5, Java 7.

Comment: Is this during development when your application is compiling and reloading other changes while running?

Comment: No, it occurs even if no compiling/reloading is happening.

Comment: Is your code getting compiled dynamically?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the context around this method, could you share more information to try to help you?

Comment: It's a sizeable application for a client so not easy to show here. But the context is unimportant, it's a standard Grails application, and the problem is not specific to this one instance. I just had it again with a `Customer.count()`, and I've had it a few times with `Sales.findAllByCustomerAndComplete()`. It's some kind of corruption, it would appear. I have no idea why I'm seeing it in just this application (I've done lots of Grails applications before).